# Is this a factor or not?

Tags: r, csv, type-conversion

I want to analyze the access log of an apache server with R. I used [this script](http://www.onehippo.com/en/resources/blogs/2012/07/Converting+Apache_x002f_Tomcat+Access+Logs+to+CSV.html) to preprocess the data, and then loaded it as csv,

```
rawdata <- read.csv("survey-log.csv")
```

I will probably have to give the data to a third party, so as a first step, I want to anonymize the IP addresses of the people who accessed the server. I think it will be enough to replace the existing IP addresses with sequentially assigned numbers, so it is clear which two requests came from the same IP.

But my first problem is that R cannot seem to decide what kind of data the "Host" column is.

```
> str(rawdata)
'data.frame':   6475 obs. of  10 variables:
$ Host         : Factor w/ 108 levels "::1","192.168.1.1",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ Log.Name     : Factor w/ 1 level "-": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ Date.Time    : Factor w/ 2398 levels "2014-10-05 06:25:02",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ Time.Zone    : Factor w/ 1 level "GMT+0200": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ Method       : Factor w/ 5 levels "CONNECT","GET",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
$ URL          : Factor w/ 621 levels "/","*","/admin",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ Response.Code: int  200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 ...
$ Bytes.Sent   : int  152 152 152 152 152 152 152 152 152 152 ...
$ Referer      : Factor w/ 190 levels "-","http://my-server
/limesurvey/",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ User.Agent   : Factor w/ 65 levels "-","Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) (internal dummy connection)",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

I thought, if "Host" is a factor, I can just replace its levels with c(1:108), and that's it. But, the problem is that it is not a factor after all:

```
 > b <- c(rawdata["Host"])
 is.factor(b)
[1] FALSE
 str(b)
List of 1
 $ Host: Factor w/ 108 levels "::1","192.168.1.1",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 as.factor(b)
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

What is happening here? Is it a factor, or not, and how do I get it to be a factor?

I'm sorry I can't provide a data sample, it is, as I said, not yet anonymized.

Comment: If somebody knows why Markdown doesn't care for the linebreaks in the blockquotes, please repair.

Comment: @Pop thank you for the edit. What made it work?

Comment: Blocks of code should be indented by 4 spaces (or select lines of unformatted code and press ctrl+k), rather than by using angle brackets (`>`). Inline code can be surrounded by backticks (`). See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) for more info.

Comment: If you try `is.factor(rawdata[["Host"]])` you will see it is. Using a single bracket returns a data frame with one column. Using a double bracket returns the contents of that column (a factor in this case). Have a look here http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html

Comment: Alternatively, access with `$`, thus: `is.factor(rawdata$Host)`.

Comment: Subsetting of data frames (lists) is nicely described [**here**](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html). "Subsetting a list [...] [u]sing `[` will always return a list; `[[` and `$` [...] let you pull out the components of the list.". "Data frames possess the characteristics of both lists and matrices: if you subset with a single vector, they behave like lists; if you subset with two vectors, they behave like matrices.", "There's an important difference if you select a single column: matrix subsetting simplifies by default, list  subsetting does not."

Comment: Also, keep in mind that `c` removes all attributes. Look what happens if you do `c(factor("a"))`.